# Отследить выполненный MySQL-запрос

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

При возникновении ошибки, при запросе в БД, хочется видеть как выглядел сам запрос, чтобы логировать его вместе с ошибкой, для полноты данных.
Подскажите, каким образом можно отследить как выглядел запрос в БД (c помощью PHP), который выдал ошибку?
т.е. `SELECT password FROM users WHERE id=1`

Comment: например, можно сохранять запрос в файл или отправлять системному logger-у.

Comment: @alex да, но как получить запрос, например, в переменную чтобы записать его в файл.

Comment: http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=EXPLAIN

Comment: @Plush, а что, разве не написанный вами код формирует запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, пишем обертку на функции mysql в которых учитываем возможность вывода ошибок совместно с текстом запроса. Пример от сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php

```
...
function db_query( $query ){
  global $b_debugmode;

  // Perform Query
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  // Check result
  // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
  if (!$result) {
    if($b_debugmode){
      $message  = '<b>Invalid query:</b><br>' . mysql_error() . '<br><br>';
      $message .= '<b>Whole query:</b><br>' . $query . '<br><br>';
      die($message); // <-- выводит текст ошибки и запроса
    }

    raise_error('db_query_error: ' . $message);
  }
  return $result;
}
...
```

P.S. Функции mysql_ уже устарели.

Answer (score 1):

Все сохраняется в query.log, но надо поставить SET global general_log = 1;

[Тут подробнее](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).